# How to run multiple simulators on Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

According to **What's new on Xcode**, Xcode 9 allows us to run multiple instance of simulator.

But what's the way to do this ?

I tried to `Build & Run` on different models but it `Quit` the current instance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I solved my problem, it's "very simple" :]

On the simulator, you must choose a new device from `Hardware > Devices`. The new instance will starts.

Then, choose your model on `Xcode`.

[Here is](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/devd856f9e4c) the solution.

Comment: Xcode 9 also has better support for attaching to multiple processes. You can install your app on multiple Simulators, start it on each Simulator, then attach to all running copies.

Comment: But how to run on two different simulators at the same time ?

Comment: this does not actually say how to run multiple simulators at the same time,

Comment: Can we run an app simultaneously on both- Device(iPhone) and Simulator?

Comment: After a lot of misleading information from Google (mostly because for the old Xcode), this is the best one

Comment: This answer just runs another instance of a phone on Xcode 9, but not with the app loaded. Also, seems like it's better to answer the question directly rather than direct to another link.

Answer (score 22):

Xcode allows you to run simulations in parallel (that can communicate with each other as well, if this is part of app functionality), but you cannot run parallel simulations on the same simulated device type (ie, you can't simulate on two iPhone 11 Pros, but your simulations could be, for instance, iPhone 11 Pro Max & iPhone 11 Pro.)

1. In Xcode, select your first simulation destination platform (Xcode-Product-Destination-select iOS simulator) and run & start a simulation (ie, ⌘B, ⌘R).
2. In Xcode, do Debug-Detach from <your_app__name>. Your app simulation will continue to run, but Xcode will no longer be connected to it.
3. Select a *different* iOS simulator device.
4. Run & start the second simulation (ie, ⌘B, ⌘R).

I suspect you could detach the second simulation from Xcode also by repeating step 2, and then reattach Xcode to the first instance, for instance if you want the ability to inspect what is happening on either simulated device, but I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 7):

You can run the multiple simulator by using xcodebuild terminal commands like this

> xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun /PathTo/.xctestrun -sdk
>   iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=name=iPhone
>   7,OS=10.3.1' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone
>   7,OS=10.3.1' -destination-timeout 300 -derivedDataPath
>   /pathtoyourderivedata
>   -only-testing:YourTestScheme/YourTestClass/YouTestMethod

The Trick here is to keep adding -destination on the devices you want to run your test on
-destination
 test-without-building  - If your project is already build.

Answer (score 5):

Just select the device name from the model list:

[image: Select multiple simulators for the same app]

[image]

Comment: but it still stop one simulator when you run app on the other one

Answer (score 4):

I had to detach my running app from the "Debug" -> "Detach from ____" menu if there was already one simulator instance running to get multiple to run at once

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgr2X.png)

Answer (score 2):

Although the accepted answer will launch another simulator instance, it doesn't actually launch your app for debugging -- unless I am missing something -- so after that, do the following:

1. Run your app 'manually' in the new simulator instance -- this assumes that it has previously been deployed to this device/iOS combination.
2. In the Xcode Debug menu choose the 'Attach to Process' menu-item and then select the instance launched in step 1 from the list of 'Likely Targets'.

And you are now running and debugging your app in both simulators.

Comment: Too bad that while it shows the devices in the dropdown over the console, the logs still appear only for the one which was started directly by xcode :(

Answer (score 2):

Perform the following in Xcode (I am using Xcode 12):

- Run the code on simulator 1
- Debug->Detach, then run on simulator 2
- Debug->Attach process, then choose from the top (likely targets)

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. check all device first:
    xcrun instruments -s devices
    2. go to base folder of proeject and open terminal
    3. run command to Build:

     xcodebuild \
      -workspace nsplus.xcworkspace \
      -scheme nsplus \
      -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max' \
      -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone SE (2nd generation)' \
      -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone 8' \
     build-for-testing

4. Run command to run these simulator:
  xcodebuild \
      -workspace nsplus.xcworkspace \
      -scheme nsplus \
      -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max' \
      -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone SE (2nd generation)' \
      -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13.5,name=iPhone 8' \
     test-without-building &
```