# How to run multiple simulators on Xcode 12 and 13?

Tags: xcode

I've seen this post for running multiple simulators on Xcode 9: [How to run multiple simulators on Xcode 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384677/how-to-run-multiple-simulators-on-xcode-9)

The working solution was to go to `Hardware > Devices` and choose a simulator from there. But I'm currently using **Xcode 13** and many developers may have the same version now. In version 12^/13, we won't find `Hardware` up top. So how do we run another simulator from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to open another simulator, you'll need to go to `File > Open Simulator` and then choose from the devices there like this:

[image: Screenshot of Mac's menu bar: File > Open Simulator > iOS 14.5 > iPhone Xs]

You're all set! I just want to share this to everyone to help save their time and avoid getting headaches (like what I've experienced) just to run another simulator on Mac.